# Custom loss function in keras with physic informed

Tags: python, keras, loss-function, autoencoder

I am trying to implement something a little complex in my opinion. I introduce you in the context. I have an autoencoder to detect failures, in which I have the mean square error between input and output. This is working with no problem. Now I am trying to implement physic informed in which I am trying to implement hard constraints making use of an expression such as

[image]

f(x) is the mean square error for my NN. And A and b are matrices with the constraints to add. Let's suppose in my example I don't have b (constants)
The custom loss function I implemented is:

```
def custom_loss_pass2(model, x_tensor, scaler):


def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        t.watch(x_tensor)
        
        f = K.mean(K.square(model(x_tensor) - x_tensor))

    grad = t.gradient(f, x_tensor)
    
    loss_PDE = K.mean(K.square(model(x_tensor) - x_tensor)) - tf.transpose(((np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(A_soc,A_soc.T)), A_soc)) @ tf.transpose(grad) )) @ (A_soc @ tf.transpose(x_tensor)) + 1/0.1 * tf.norm(A_soc @ tf.transpose(x_tensor))

    return loss_PDE
return custom_loss
```

This is training, but the loss is so high in comparison with just the mean square error. So the term I am adding is so high. I am scaling the dataset. So I can't just multiply by a matrix A not scaled. I tried to scale directly the matrix A like

```
A_soc = scaler.transform(np.array([["array here with the constraints"]]))
```

I also tried to add this matrix to the input of the scale to consider it.
I tried to implement the scale_inverse to the data to calculate just the loss function. The problem is that it is not possible to implement the inverse in one tensor.

Anyone has any idea why this is not working? are you able to see another fail or something I am not considering?

Thank you so much